# How to get the UserID to send a private message through SignalR.Core 3.0 from Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, asp.net-core, signalr

I am trying to create a chat in Xamarin that sends private messages. For now I have been able to send messages to a specific group or to all users but I don't know how from the client side I get the UserID to send a private message.

I have tried the Microsoft documentation but all it shows is how to configure on the server side but there are no examples of how it would be on the client side.

I have tried with this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/groups?view=aspnetcore-2.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#IUserIdProvider

But I can't find documentation or an example of how to find the UserID from the client side to be able to send the message or maybe I have a bad perception of how the problem should be addressed.

**Server Side:**

```cs
public class ChatHub : Hub
{

    public async Task JoinChat(string user)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("JoinChat", user);
    }

    public async Task LeaveChat(string user)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("LeaveChat", user);
    }

    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }

    public void BroadcastMessage(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.SendAsync("broadcastMessage", name, message);
    }

    public void Echo(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).SendAsync("echo", name, message + " (echo from server)");
    }

    public async Task AddToGroup(string groupName, string user)
    {
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);

        await Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync("Entered", user);
        //await Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync("Entered", "_SYSTEM_", $"{user} joined {groupName} with connectionId {Context.ConnectionId}");
    }

    public async Task RemoveFromGroup(string groupName, string user)
    {
        await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
        //await Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).SendAsync("Left", "_SYSTEM_", $"{user} leaved {groupName}");
        await Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync("Left", user);
        //await Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync("Left", "_SYSTEM_", $"{user} leaved {groupName}");
    }

    public async Task SendMessageGroup(string groupName, string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }
    //**//

    public void SendGroups(string name, IReadOnlyList<string> groups, string message)
    {
        Clients.Groups(groups).SendAsync("echo", name, message);
    }

    public void SendGroupExcept(string name, string groupName, IReadOnlyList<string> connectionIdExcept, string message)
    {
        Clients.GroupExcept(groupName, connectionIdExcept).SendAsync("echo", name, message);
    }

    public void SendUser(string name, string userId, string message)
    {
        Clients.User(userId).SendAsync("echo", name, message);
    }

    public void SendUsers(string name, IReadOnlyList<string> userIds, string message)
    {
        Clients.Users(userIds).SendAsync("echo", name, message);
    }

}
```

```cs
public class CustomUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
    public virtual string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)
    {
       // return connection.User?.Identity?.Name;
        return connection.User?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;
    }
}
```

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .WithOrigins("http://localhost:5002");
    }));
    services.AddSignalR();
    services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, CustomUserIdProvider>();
}
```

**Client Side:**

**Taken from James Montemagno from:**
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/XamChat

```js
public class ChatService
{
    public event EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> OnReceivedMessage;
    public event EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> OnEnteredOrExited;
    public event EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> OnConnectionClosed;

    HubConnection hubConnection;
    Random random;

    bool IsConnected { get; set; }
    Dictionary<string, string> ActiveChannels { get; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();


    public void Init(string urlRoot, bool useHttps)
    {
        random = new Random();

        var port = (urlRoot == "localhost" || urlRoot == "10.0.2.2") ?
            (useHttps ? ":5001" : ":5000") :
            string.Empty;

        var url = $"http{(useHttps ? "s" : string.Empty)}://{urlRoot}{port}/hubs/chat";
        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl(url)
        .Build();

        hubConnection.Closed += async (error) =>
        {
            OnConnectionClosed?.Invoke(this, new MessageEventArgs("Connection closed...", string.Empty));
            IsConnected = false;
            await Task.Delay(random.Next(0, 5) * 1000);
            try
            {
                await ConnectAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Exception!
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        };

        hubConnection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) =>
        {
            OnReceivedMessage?.Invoke(this, new MessageEventArgs(message, user));
        });

        hubConnection.On<string>("Entered", (user) =>
        {
            OnEnteredOrExited?.Invoke(this, new MessageEventArgs($"{user} entered.", user));
        });


        hubConnection.On<string>("Left", (user) =>
        {
            OnEnteredOrExited?.Invoke(this, new MessageEventArgs($"{user} left.", user));
        });


        hubConnection.On<string>("EnteredOrLeft", (message) =>
        {
            OnEnteredOrExited?.Invoke(this, new MessageEventArgs(message, message));
        });
    }

    public async Task ConnectAsync()
    {
        if (IsConnected)
            return;

        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
        IsConnected = true;
    }

    public async Task DisconnectAsync()
    {
        if (!IsConnected)
            return;

        try
        {
            await hubConnection.DisposeAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        ActiveChannels.Clear();
        IsConnected = false;
    }

    public async Task LeaveChannelAsync(string group, string userName)
    {
        if (!IsConnected || !ActiveChannels.ContainsKey(group))
            return;

        await hubConnection.SendAsync("RemoveFromGroup", group, userName);

        ActiveChannels.Remove(group);
    }

    public async Task JoinChannelAsync(string group, string userName)
    {
        if (!IsConnected || ActiveChannels.ContainsKey(group))
            return;

        await hubConnection.SendAsync("AddToGroup", group, userName);
        ActiveChannels.Add(group, userName);

    }

    public async Task SendMessageAsync(string group, string userName, string message)
    {
        if (!IsConnected)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Not connected");

        await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("SendMessageGroup",
                group,
                userName,
                message);
    }

    public async Task SendMessageUserAsync(string group, string userName, string message)
    {
        if (!IsConnected)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Not connected");

        await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("SendUser",
                userName,
                "10",
                message);
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you managing identity on the client?

Comment: @Jason I don't really know how to handle, to send group messages it only requires a group name to join that group and then a username and message.          await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("SendMessageGroup",
                    group,
                    userName,
                    message); and to send a message to everyone I use  await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("SendMessage", user, message); but I know that to send a private message I need the UserId, that's where I am confused.

Comment: @Ivanrlg please add your hub code and client side code. So I will see what you are missing to do what you want.

Comment: @Kiril1512 ok, I'm going to add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you missing is to map connections to users. I would create for example a dynamic list of users and map them every time that user connects. For example, having a method to return a connectionId:

```cs
public string GetConnectionId()
{
   return this.Context.ConnectionId;
}
```

And after recieve the connectionId you can call a method to map the user to connection. So if you need to send a message to a specific user, you can search the user in your list, and get the connectionId of that specific user so you can do send him a message like:

```cs
Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync(from, to, message);
```

You can read [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections) about this matter, although is for the old SignalR, you can use the same logic and adapt it for your needs.

Comment: Well, no don't expose the connection id, because it means anybody can send to anyone else (unless that's what you wanted). Use actual user identities instead if you want something more real and secure